# Rails + Money gem: Validation that one Money field is greater than another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having trouble with a validation for making sure that one column is greater than another using the money rails gem (https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails).

I have a `FlatCoupon` model. It has two fields: `minimum_purchase_amount` (money), and `value` (decimal).

Schema:

```
create_table "coupons", force: true do |t|
  ...
  t.integer  "minimum_purchase_amount_cents",                             default: 0,     null: false
  t.string   "minimum_purchase_amount_currency",                          default: "USD", null: false
  t.decimal  "value",                            precision: 30, scale: 2
```

When I add this validation to my `FlatCoupon` model:

```
class FlatCoupon < Coupon
  monetize :minimum_purchase_amount_cents
  validates :minimum_purchase_amount, numericality: { greater_than: ->(flat_coupon) { Money.new(flat_coupon.value*100) }, message: "must be more than the discount amount." }, 
            if: Proc.new { |c| c.value.present? }
```

It causes my FactoryGirl factory to fail:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :flat_coupon do
    ...
    minimum_purchase_amount 30.33
    value 12.00
  end
end
```

Isn't the value attribute set to something smaller than minimum_purchase_amount?? Look at my console:

```
    irb(main):001:0> f = FactoryGirl.build(:flat_coupon)
    => #<FlatCoupon id: nil, start_date: "2014-06-18 00:00:00", end_date: "2014-06-20 00:00:00", minimum_purchase_amount_cents: 3033, minimum_purchase_amount_currency: "USD", value: #<BigDecimal:7fe37f8043e0,'0.12E2',9(45)>, type: "FlatCoupon", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, name: "Flat!", site_wide: nil, code: "BBB321">
    irb(main):002:0> f.valid?
      Coupon Exists (0.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `coupons`  WHERE `coupons`.`code` = BINARY 'BBB321' LIMIT 1
    => false
    irb(main):003:0> f.errors
    => #<ActiveModel::Errors:0x007fe37f8b1540 @base=#<FlatCoupon id: nil, start_date: "2014-06-18 00:00:00", end_date: "2014-06-20 00:00:00", minimum_purchase_amount_cents: 3033, minimum_purchase_amount_currency: "USD", value: #<BigDecimal:7fe37f8043e0,'0.12E2',9(45)>, type: "FlatCoupon", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, name: "Flat!", site_wide: nil, code: "BBB321">, @messages={:minimum_purchase_amount=>["must be more than the discount amount."]}>
    irb(main):004:0> f.minimum_purchase_amount > Money.new(f.value*100)
    => true
```

Can anyone help me?

Even when I change my validation to print out the values one by one:

```
validates_numericality_of :minimum_purchase_amount, greater_than: ->(flat_coupon) { 
  puts Money.new(flat_coupon.value*100);
  puts flat_coupon.minimum_purchase_amount;
  puts flat_coupon.minimum_purchase_amount > Money.new(flat_coupon.value*100);
  Money.new(flat_coupon.value*100) }
```

It still does this:

```
    Nets-Mac-Pro:ilook emai$ be rails c
    Loading development environment (Rails 4.1.1)
    irb(main):001:0> flat_coupon = FactoryGirl.build(:flat_coupon)
    => #<FlatCoupon id: nil, start_date: "2014-06-18 00:00:00", end_date: "2014-06-20 00:00:00", minimum_purchase_amount_cents: 3033, minimum_purchase_amount_currency: "USD", value: #<BigDecimal:7fe379732ad0,'0.12E2',9(45)>, type: "FlatCoupon", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, name: "Flat!", site_wide: nil, code: "BBB321">
    irb(main):002:0> flat_coupon.valid?
      Coupon Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM `coupons`  WHERE `coupons`.`code` = BINARY 'BBB321' LIMIT 1
    12.00
    30.33
    true
    => false
```

What's the deal? Is this a bug?

P.S. I can't change the value to a money value in the database because of business reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similiar case, but I am not using built in validators. Simply write your own, so you can handle the validation with the attributes as you like.
Something like this should do the trick.

```
class FlatCoupon < Coupon
    validate :validate_prices

    def validate_prices
      if value <= minimum_purchase_amount_cents
        errors.add(:value, 'must be more than the discount amount')
      end
    end
 end
```